# Multiple Click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show/hide content on a page that contains the same class on multiple HTML elements. However, when I click on one of the anchor links, it opens BOTH paragraphs, rather than only the paragraph that I am trying to open. How do I fix this so that the Read more only toggles the intended paragraph?

JS:

```
$('.show-more').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
if($('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '96px'){
    $('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
    $(this).text('Read more');
}else{
    $('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});
    var xx = $('.show-more-snippet').height();
    $('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'96px'});
    $('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
    $(this).text('Read less');
}   });   });
```

HTML:

```
<div><p class="show-more-snippet"> Some first paragraph text</p>
          <a class="show-more" href="#">Read more</a> </div>
<div><p class="show-more-snippet"> Some second paragraph text</p>
          <a class="show-more" href="#">Read more</a> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.show-more-snippet {
    height:16px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this: http://jsfiddle.net/6jnwmkp4/

```
$('.show-more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '96px'){
        $(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
        $(this).text('Read more');
    }else{
        $(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});
        var xx = $(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').height();
        $(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'96px'});
        $(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
        $(this).text('Read less');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to change all of `$('.show-more-snippet')` with `$(this).prev()`. This will give you the access to the `p` that is just before the button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your callback you are using a class `show-more-snippet` which is used by both paragraph elements. That's why both of them are getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

Given your HTML structure, you need to use `.parent().find()` in your jQuery. This will target the clicked elements sibling rather than all elements with the `.show-more-snippet` class.

eg.

```
if($(this).parent().find('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '96px')...
```

and

```
$(this).parent().find('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
```

etc.

**EDIT:** A better way to do it would be to use `.siblings()` like so:

eg.

```
if($(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '96px')...
```

and

```
$(this).siblings('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.show-more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  //write closing logic to close all  if you want to close other tab on class name
    $('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});

   //Then open this tab . 

  if($(this).css('height') != '96px'){
$(this).stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
$(this).text('Read more');
}else{
$(this).css({height:'100%'});
var xx = $(this).height();
$(this).css({height:'96px'});
$(this).stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
$(this).text('Read less');
   }   });   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `prev` for that. see below code shipment.

**`Jquery`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show-more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '96px'){
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
        $(this).text('Read more');
    }else{
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});
        var xx = $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').height();
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'96px'});
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
        $(this).text('Read less');
    }   
    });
});
```

**`HTML`**

```
<div>
    <p class="show-more-snippet"> Some first paragraph text</p>
    <a class="show-more" href="#">Read more</a> 
</div>
<div>
    <p class="show-more-snippet"> Some second paragraph text</p>
    <a class="show-more" href="#">Read more</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select particular prev div.

```
$('.show-more').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
if($(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '96px'){
    $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
    $(this).text('Read more');
}else{
    $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});
    var xx = $('.show-more-snippet').height();
    $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'96px'});
    $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
    $(this).text('Read less');
}   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is that you are not specifying which of the `<p class=".show-more-snippet"></p>` to use.** This should be the one you clicked the "show more" button for.

You can solve this using the `e` value in your click listener. See below for `var paragraph` which gets the proper `<p>` element which you can use for what  you need to do.

Just replace `$('.show-more-snippet')` with `$(paragraph)` in your code.

**Solution:**

```
$('.show-more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the correct paragraph
    var paragraph = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.show-more-snippet');

    if ($(paragraph).css('height') != '96px') {
        $(paragraph).stop().animate({height: '96px'}, 200);
        // ... etc ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add active class on the div parent of the anchor you click, other divs remove active class. This way will simplify your code.

in code

```
$('.show-more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.show-more-snippet.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.show-more-snippet').addClass('active');
});
```

In css

```
.show-more-snippet.active {
    height:96px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you have got too many answers for your problem above but If you want a clean solution using some external *js* then you can use expander.**

main source:[here](http://www.discussdesk.com/read-more-less-content-in-jquery-expander-plugin.htm)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.show-more-snippet').expander({
      slicePoint: 280, //It is the number of characters at which the contents will be sliced into two parts.
      widow: 2,
      expandSpeed: 0, // It is the time in second to show and hide the content.
      userCollapseText: 'Read Less (-)' // Specify your desired word default is Less.
    });

    $('div.show-more-snippet').expander();

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.discussdesk.com/online_demo/read-more-less-content-in-jquery-expander-plugin/jquery.expander.js"></script>

<div class="show-more-snippet">

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor pulvinar mi in pellentesque. In et faucibus nisi. Vivamus nec bibendum eros. Ut in augue ac leo facilisis lobortis. Cras sit amet pulvinar massa. Donec sed tempus velit. Praesent dignissim iaculis pretium.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor pulvinar mi in pellentesque. In et faucibus nisi. Vivamus nec bibendum eros. Ut in augue ac leo facilisis lobortis. Cras sit amet pulvinar massa. Donec sed tempus velit. Praesent dignissim iaculis pretium.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor pulvinar mi in pellentesque. In et faucibus nisi. Vivamus nec bibendum eros. Ut in augue ac leo facilisis lobortis. Cras sit amet pulvinar massa. Donec sed tempus velit. Praesent dignissim iaculis pretium.</p>
</div>

<div class="show-more-snippet">

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor pulvinar mi in pellentesque. In et faucibus nisi. Vivamus nec bibendum eros. Ut in augue ac leo facilisis lobortis. Cras sit amet pulvinar massa. Donec sed tempus velit. Praesent dignissim iaculis pretium.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor pulvinar mi in pellentesque. In et faucibus nisi. Vivamus nec bibendum eros. Ut in augue ac leo facilisis lobortis. Cras sit amet pulvinar massa. Donec sed tempus velit. Praesent dignissim iaculis pretium.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor pulvinar mi in pellentesque. In et faucibus nisi. Vivamus nec bibendum eros. Ut in augue ac leo facilisis lobortis. Cras sit amet pulvinar massa. Donec sed tempus velit. Praesent dignissim iaculis pretium.</p>
</div>
```